# alt tab bug with Thunderbird

Tags: shortcut-keys, thunderbird, 21.10

Whenever I have the Thunderbird screen in focus and use alt tab to change windows something strange happens. The alt tab function is disabled (no longer works) and this behaviour can only be rectified by a reboot. I think this is a bug with Thunderbird. I am using Ubuntu 21.10

Where should I report this? Is this issue specific to Ubuntu 21.10 or should the Thunderbird people be informed?

Comment: Sorry. I meant alt tab. I've edited my question.

Comment: There is a similar bug (or there was one, at least) that caused your apps to disappear from the taskbar, as well as preventing Alt Tab from working. Is that what you are seeing? This could temporarily be resolved by pressing Alt + F2 and entering `restart`, rather than a complete reboot.

Comment: There is a known bug in Thunderbird which I think is what you have going on. See here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1950925