# sometimes Thunderbird doesn't quit properly and switching windows with ALT+TAB doesn't work: how to solve?

Tags: thunderbird, panel, application-switcher

Sometimes Thunderbird freezes on the Panel after quiting the program and simultaniously switching windows with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> doesn't work anymore.

On my computer I can reproduce it this way:

Ubuntu 21.10
Thunderbird 91.5.0 (64-bit)

step 1: open a Terminal window
step 2: open a second Terminal window
*note: it can also be any other window of another program, but for this test I used Terminal windows*
step 3: open Thunderbird
step 4: check if with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> you can switch normally between all 3 the windows; if so, proceed.
*note: check also if <kbd>SUPER</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> switches normally between the programs Terminal and Thunderbird*
step 5: go to Thunderbird and start a new message with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>
step 6: write a test message and send it (with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>)
*note: sending a message is essential, I can't reproduce the error if I only open Thunderbird and only read messages*
step 7: at this point the error/bug occurs: with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> I can't switch anymore to the opened Terminal windows.
*note that <kbd>SUPER</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> still works normally*
Not only the window switching is malfunctioning right now, but also Thunderbird doesn't quit anymore as it should:
step 8: go with the still functioning super key (windows key) <kbd>SUPER</kbd> to the opened Terminal windows and close them.
step 9: go to the opened Thunderbird window and close it under File->Quit (or with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>)
step 10: hover with the mouse over the (side) Panel and see that Thunderbird is indicated still as running, even though it has been closed already. 
step 11: right-click on the Thunderbird symbol in the panel and try to close the program with Quit there: this doesn't work and on my computer the menu that appears after right-clicking on Thunderbird in the panel stays open and doesn't go away anymore at all.

What can cause this problem? How can I debug it myself further?

*Someone else already asked this question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1390268/alt-tab-bug-with-thunderbird/1390733), but following the suggestion in a comment there I re-post the same question in my own words here.*

Comment: This is a very high level of care, I would be very surprised if a Stack Exchange community would try to stifle such good content.

Comment: @mickmackusa Thank you for the guidance you gave me on how and where I should post my question!

Comment: But isn't this the bug linked to in the other question? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/thunderbird/+bug/1932328

Comment: What is your concern, @Jos?

Comment: @Jos the bug link in the other question seems to be describing a slightly different situation. The bug link you write in your comment actually does exactly describe the same problem. So please learn me how to interpret that bug page: on top of it I see "status: invalid" and "unassigned". At the bottom of the bug discussion (comment #72) I read that the status (in mutter-ubuntu) changed from "In progress" to "Fix Released". What does this mean for me as an end user? Should I wait for the next release of Ubuntu or can I do something else to fix this properly (not with a workaround please)?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on Ubuntu 21.10 with Th 91.5.0 - Oops, yes, I am on Xorg, so may be a Wayland issue indeed. Try running ` MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND=1 thunderbird` if not already, otherways turn around and have thunderbird run on xwayland by removing the variable to see if the issue disappears.

Comment: I think the issue report linked by @jos may be relevant here. My suggestion is also there in the commants, see #18

Comment: @mickmackusa Although this is undoubtedly an important issue, bug reports are offtopic on this site. That is all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu 21.10 defaults to Wayland, even after an upgrade. The issue you experience agrees with the symptoms described in [an existing bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/thunderbird/+bug/1932328). This will need to be fixed by the upstream developpers. In the mean time you can

- Run thunderbird on `xwayland` (an Xorg emulation layer on Wayland) instead. This involves commenting out the line `export MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND=1` in `/usr/lib/thunderbird/thunderbird.sh`.
- Move back to using Xorg: on the login screen, click the cog wheel and select the Xorg session of Ubuntu

*Note* As commented [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/telegram-desktop/+bug/1916469/comments/20), updates will revert the changes to `/usr/lib/thunderbird/thunderbird.sh`. To avoid this:

1. Copy `/usr/lib/thunderbird/thunderbird.sh` to `/usr/local/lib/thunderbird/thunderbird.sh` and make the changes in the copy
2. Create a symlink to your custom wrapper script in `/usr/local/bin`, i.e. `ls -s ../local/lib/thunderbird/thunderbird.sh /usr/local/bin/thunderbird`

The symlink in `/usr/local/bin` overrides the one installed with thunderbird. Both the custom link and wrapper script will not be affected by any future update of thunderbird.

Comment: Thank you. I choose for now the quick and easy option: logging in with Xorg and that solves the issue completely. Maybe I'll try later the xwayland option with the symlink fix if I later would feel the need for Wayland for other reasons. Just wondering why Ubuntu choosed to make Wayland the default X-server if a very common application as TB still has a bug with Wayland? Does Ubuntu that way try to push TB developpers towards Wayland compatibility or is this just a bug nobody could have foreseen and apparently is not that easy to fix (because already known for more than half a year)?